# How to use flutter_webview_plugin with AndroidX in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, androidx, flutterwebviewplugin

I am making a flutter project witch uses the flutter webview plugin. The package worked until i migrated to AndroidX. How can I use this package with AndroidX? Or does anyone know a package that looks like this one? I need to set a listener on the link to get a redirect url and acces code. (Login through a web browser)

The app is working when I don't install the package but crashes when I install the package.

Comment: I am using the same package. All I did was adding `android.useAndroidX=true` and 
`android.enableJetifier=true` to `android/gradle.properties`

Comment: @ArashMohammadi that's not working for me, not even when I start a new project from scatch with use AndroidX already checked. Which version are u using?

Comment: It is the `flutter_webview_plugin: ^0.3.8`. I created the project using command line in VsCode. There were no use AndroidX in it. Try creating new project with cmd, then add those lines that I mentioned in earlier comment. Nothing else, just these steps. If that does not work, I'll share my gradle, pubspec and ... .

Answer (score 0):

In my **pubspec.yaml** I updated the version from `0.3.5` to `0.3.8`. It solved the problem for me.

```
dependencies:
  flutter_webview_plugin: ^0.3.8
```